# Flash - ExternalInterface calling a JavaScript function inside an AMD/RequireJS module

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, requirejs, externalinterface

Is there any way for Flash's ActionScript3 to communicate with a JavaScript function defined inside an AMD module - ie. not directly exposed to the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

Create a JS function on the global scope which in turn calls the function inside the AMD module.

-or-

write the global js function in the external interface call:

```
ExternalInterface.call( "function uniqueFunctionName(){ myModule.foo(); }" );
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid attaching anything to the global scope for security reasons (so the methods can't be invoked by typing `javascript:fn();` into the address bar of the browser).

Comment: added another solution to my answer